# Error in handling reponse from remote true Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails remote true for ajax calls, but I have error in handling the response form controller.

What I am doing is I have placed a form in partial which I render in the view for the first time, and I have also given it a id in html options for form_for. I have also applied some jQuery on that form like on save and cancel button and one script for date picker on one of its field.

As I handle the response from server using format.js for rendering js file, in which I have placed the code as follows

```
if @vairable.save
 format.js { render 'some-file' }
else
 format.js { render 'something'}
end
```

If the variable saved successfully I close the form properly, but if validations occur I render the form again by writing JavaScript code in js.erb file. I have problem in handing this response. The errors are displaying properly but when the form renders again with errors, the jQuery events applied to its fields and button, do not work. The jQuery events don't take place.

This problem only occurs when the model validations occurs and the validation rails are displayed with the new render form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your response in a `respond_to` block like this:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  if @variable.save
    format.js { render 'some-file' }
  else
    format.js { render 'something'}
  end  
end
```

Edit: Your jQuery tags should be changed to `$(document).on(...)`. Eg.

```
#change this:
$("#your-target-id").click(function(){
  alert("This doesn't work after your have submitted via ajax")
});

#to this:
$(document).on("click", "#your-target-id", function() {
  alert("This should work after ajax submission, and when errors are displayed");
});
```

Comment: i am doing this, but after that the jquery elements not working

Comment: this problem only occurs when the model validations occurs and the validation rails are displayed with the new render form.

Comment: This is a issue with jQuery, not rails. You should change all your jQuery event handler methods to `on` and `live` instead of methods  like `click`. So fx `$("form").click(function(){});` would be `$(document).on('click', 'form', function(){...});` See more here http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: i have tried jquery .on method, its not working me. Please help in this issue, i am not getting it.

Comment: i have pasted my code at this link http://pastebin.com/fxqmM0Mi. Visit  it. I am rendering the partial that contains a remote true form and a select tag having jquery event. First time it forms properly but after having validation fails i render the form again with errors. At that time the jquery event don't works.

Comment: Your jQuery script should look like `$(document).on("click", "#offer_template", function() {...})`. See http://pastebin.com/5sUEQsHv

Comment: yes my problem is solved fully, but i cant accept it as of my reputation is not much :(

Comment: you please give yes to my questions, which can help me in my points. thanks

Comment: I also need some help in other task. I am trying to make a filtering page in which i have some categories with check boxes in them. As i click the check box's, my result get filtered by them. Can you suggest me something for it?

Comment: You should create a new question for this :)

Comment: ok, i will do it and paste a link for that here. you can get the question then.

Comment: hey, i have created a question. follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579238/rails-query-interface-where-clause-issue

Comment: same problem as above i also getting in jquery datepicker. First time its working properly but after render form again, its not working. I have used $('#datepicker').datepicker{} function of jquery. can you help me in this also

Comment: You could do one of two things:
1. use `$(document).on('load', '#datepicker', function(){$(this).datepicker()});` 
2. In the `something.js.erb` template you render, add the ` $('#datepicker').datepicker();` function call.

Comment: not working. my code is <script>
                      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                        minDate: 0,
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        //comment the beforeShow handler if you want to see the ugly overlay
                        beforeShow: function() {
                          setTimeout(function(){
                            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                          }, 0);
                        }
                      });
                    </script>

Comment: Can you add the code for the template rendered with: 'format.js { render 'something'}', in your question?

Comment: you told me the solution for that on jquery method, this method is working properly but now i have comes out with a issue because of this. After the validation errors displayed, i again click on my submit button for my remote true form. It send a html request at back and my page redirect to that, because of this. How to resolve it?