# Rails query interface where clause issue?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am try to run the SQK query as follows

```
@applicants = Applicant.where("applicants.first_name LIKE ? AND applicants.status = ?", "%#{people}%", ["new", "in-review"] )
```

I am getting a MySQL error as :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `applicants`.* FROM `applicants`  WHERE (applicants.first_name LIKE '%sh%' AND applicants.status = 'new','in-review')):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `IN` clause of mysql

```
@applicants = Applicant.where("applicants.first_name LIKE ? AND 
                               applicants.status in (?)", 
                               "%#{people}%", ["new", "in-review"] )
```

Comment: @applicants = Applicant.includes(:jobs).where("applicants.first_name LIKE ? AND applicants.location LIKE ? AND jobs.job_title LIKE ?", "%#{people}%", "%#{location}%", "%#{more_job}%")

Comment: thanks , it works for me but a little change. Instead of includes(:jobs), I have used includes(:job)

Answer (score 4):

If you want pass an array it should be better to write

```
@applicants = Applicant
    .where("applicants.first_name LIKE ?", "%#{people}%")
    .where(status: ["new", "in-review"])
```

Or use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.

```
@applicants = Applicant.where{ (status.in(["new", "in-review"]) & (first_name =~ "%#{people}%") }
```

Comment: can you help me in this query. follow the link pastebin.com/2vup4PWD

Comment: you cannot use object-oriented notation applicants.job.job_title, because as I understand, job_title is a column of jobs table. You need to JOIN jobs table. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables